# Performance wise, should I use @font-face or should I "draw" the text with Javascript and HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, canvas, font-face

The situation I have is that I have to create a web version of a physical fashion magazine. The magazine cover has 5 different fonts with 5 different styles. Performance wise, should I use @font-face or should I "draw" the text with Javascript and HTML canvas?

EDIT: Web version is targeted for iPad, I'll be build the web app and then use PhoneGap so I can submit the app to the App store.

Comment: But you would still need to load the font files for the CANVAS text, too, wouldn't you?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas makes a VERY good point - also, you'll be limiting the accessibility by using a CANVAS element to display text. This should be avoided especially for a text based media site.

Comment: @rlemon It my assumption is true, then this question doesn't make sense, since CANVAS wouldn't be an *alternative* to `@font-face`. However, I guess it is possible to create fonts "manually" with rectangles, and circles, so it could be that OP meant that.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas regardless it seems pointless, IF (and that is a big IF) the OP finds a way to produce these font faces ***faster*** than using CSS alternative, the drawbacks where accessibility and SEO are concerned defiantly (IMO) outweigh any nominal speed benefits.

Comment: Sorry, you are on your own. Trying to be helpful here is obviously not encouraged. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I meant drawing the text instead of using @font-face. SEO and other usual problems are not a concern since this will be an app store app targeted for iPad, so lot of usual problems go out the window.

Comment: @Guffa I'm unsure what you are referring to.

Comment: @Andrija: I deleted my answer, it didn't seem welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only assumptions can be made in regards to this answer because so much is dependant on:

1. The OS and browser because it is the OS and browser that do the work to pretty up the HTML document.
2. The bandwidth speed of the people opening up your web page. With the CSS approach its another resource (or multiple resource for fonts as well) that need to be downloaded. Yes agreed this is less of an impact these days.
3. What about the limitations of Canvas, e.g. Internationalization, search engine optimisation, integration with web content management, accessibility, etc... Most possible but effort required.
4. Finally, the effort to do the canvas vs CSS approach. I'd imagine it would be quicker to implement with CSS.

Personally I'd stick with CSS for this, I like to separate my content (HTML), presentation (CSS) and logic (JavaScript) a [guide](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/web-development-style-guide) only!

Answer (score 0):

CSS is generally faster to render than canvas elements. I imagine the exact performance varies from browser to browser, but you can check [this link](http://jsperf.com/opacity-animations-using-css-vs-html5-canvas) to make a comparison between the same operation using CSS and canvas.

In my computer, this is the result (its not fonts but it may serve as reference):
[image]